# PHP - Difference between session_cache_limiter() and headers?

Tags: php, caching, cache-control

I was wondering, if there is any difference between them:

```
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
```

and headers:

```
header("Cache-Control:no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control:post-check=0,pre-check=0",false);
header("Pragma:no-cache");
```

Assuming that I don't want any cache.

Comment: session_cache_limiter for SESSION storage, header for http data output

Comment: so if I use session_cache_limiter without a session, is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all who wandered here from google search and feel lost ...

Call `session_cache_limiter` **before** `session_start` if you use session.

Send headers directly, if you don't use session, because `session_cache_limiter` only works in combination with `session_start`.